# How do I ignore empty tags with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this webpage:

```
text = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/on-small-business/post/how-to-breed-big-innovation-inside-a-small-business/2013/03/26/b1a8953e-962a-11e2-9e23-09dce87f75a1_blog.html', timeout=7.00).text)
```

I have a beautiful soup function that pulls all `<ul>` tags without attributes and with `<li>` tags that do not contain attributes and without `<a>` tag children:

```
def pull_ul(tag):
        return tag.name == 'ul' and not tag.attrs and not tag.li.attrs and not tag.a  
ul_tags = text.find_all(pull_ul)
print ul_tags
```

When I run this, I get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

So I modify the function to:

```
def pull_ul(tag):
        return tag.name == 'ul' and not tag.attrs and not tag.a
```

And that outputs:

```
[<ul></ul>, <ul> <li class="report-button" id="flag-spam">Spam</li> <li class="report-button" id="flag-offensive">Offensive</li> <li class="report-button" id="flag-disagree">Disagree</li> <li class="report-button" id="flag-offtopic">Off-Topic</li> </ul>]
```

Which tells me that the part that's generating the error is the empty tag `<ul></ul>`

Is there a way to rewrite that function to make it ignore all instances of empty tags that trip up the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just add an additional check if `tag.li` is truthy:

```
def pull_ul(tag):
    return tag.name == 'ul' and \
           not tag.attrs and \
           tag.li and \ # < HERE
           not tag.li.attrs and \
           not tag.a
```